# Does audio.loadSound, loads audio files synchronously?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a game that heavily depends on audio API of Corona SDK. The game neads to load a couple of sounds (wavs) and a relatively big background music (+15mb) I don't want to steam the files couse of a statement that I read in corona guides.

> Note that streamed files may have a slightly higher latency cost and CPU cost than files loaded with audio.loadSound().

I'm using composer API and I'm planning to develop a loading screen based on event cycle.

My question is can I depend on audio API that if I put all of my `loadSound`s to the `create` event handler and they all going to load synchronously and then the `show` event will be dispatched after all of audio files loaded?..

...Or should I use a diffrent approach for my loading screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe they are loaded synchronously.

On my apps with a larger background music file the load screen will take longer on slower devices.  So it blocks until it is loaded.

I would imagine this is the case since there is no mechanism to 'query' or a callback for when audio is loaded if it was asynchronous.

But don't take my word for it, test it.

PS: Your solution does seem to be solid though, that's about what I do.